# Product Associate drop down inventory stock value display

Tags: magento-1.9

On the product page, i have to display associated product inventory stock qty on a dropdown. Currently its display undefined.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to write like this. It will work.

```
$products=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
foreach($products as $_product){

$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);

echo $stock->getQty();

}
```

Comment: Thanks, Rama but please tell me where I should put this code.